# Bucle while infinito

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un problema de java que consiste hallar cuantas iteraciones se necesita hasta llegar a la constante de kaprekar:

1. Elige un número de cuatro dígitos que tenga al menos dos diferentes (es válido colocar el dígito 0 al principio, por lo que el número 0009 es válido).
2. Coloca sus dígitos en orden ascendente y en orden descendente para formar dos nuevos números. Puedes añadir los dígitos 0 que necesites al principio.
3. Resta el menor al mayor.
4. Vuelve al paso 2.
   Este problema lo saque de [acepta el reto](https://www.aceptaelreto.com/).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kaprekar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int KAPREKAR = 6174;
        int casos, numAsc, numDes;
        int numero = 0;
        int cont = 0;
        int resta = 0;
        int contador = 0;

        System.out.println("Escribe el numero de casos");
        casos = entrada.nextInt();

        while(contador < casos){
            numero = entrada.nextInt();

            if(contDig(numero) >= 4){
                continue;
            }else if(numero == KAPREKAR){
                System.out.println("0");
                continue;
            }else if(numDig(numero) == 0){
                System.out.println("8");
                continue;
            }else{
                numAsc = ordAsc(numero);
                numDes = ordDes(numero);

                while(resta == KAPREKAR){

                    if(numAsc > numDes){
                        resta = numAsc - numDes;
                        numAsc = ordAsc(resta);
                        numDes = ordDes(resta);
                    }else if(numDes > numAsc){
                        resta = numDes - numAsc;
                        numAsc = ordAsc(resta);
                        numDes = ordDes(resta);
                    }

                    cont++;
                }

                System.out.println(cont);
                cont = 0;
            }
            contador++;
        }
    }

    public static int contDig(int n){
        //Cuenta el numero de digitos de un numero
        int contador = 0;
        String nS = Integer.toString(n);

        for(int i = 0; i <= nS.length(); i++){
            contador = i;
        }

        return contador;
    }

    public static int numDig(int n){
        //Cuenta el numero de digitos distintos de un numero
        ArrayList<Integer> num1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> num2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int contador = 0;
        String nS = Integer.toString(n);

        for(int i = 0; i < nS.length(); i++){
            num1.add(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(nS.charAt(i))));
            num2.add(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(nS.charAt(i))));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < num1.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < num2.size(); j++){
                if(num1.get(i) != num2.get(j)){
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(contador > 0){
            return contador / 4;
        }else{
            return contador;
        }
    }

    public static int ordAsc(int n){
        int lisNum[] = new int [4];

        int numAsc;
        String nS = Integer.toString(n);
        String nA = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < nS.length(); i++){
            lisNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(nS.charAt(i)));
        }

        Arrays.sort(lisNum);

        for(int i = 0; i < lisNum.length; i++){
            nA += Integer.toString(lisNum[i]);
        }

        numAsc = Integer.parseInt(nA);

        return numAsc;
    }

    public static int ordDes(int n){
        int numAsc = ordAsc(n);
        int numDes;

        String nA = Integer.toString(numAsc);
        String nD = "";

        for(int i = nA.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            nD += nA.charAt(i);
        }

        numDes = Integer.parseInt(nD);

        return numDes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya solucione el problema. Abajo en las respuestas dejo el código, aunque quedaría agradecido si me pudieran ayudar a solución mas eficiente

Answer (score 1):

Dejo un enlace al pdf donde podéis consultar el problema que he realizado [aquí](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kmhKAZ_-wr-WP0vdx0CFvnHACo70HET2/view?usp=sharing)
En el código puse algunos comentarios que junto con el problema espero que os aclare lo que estoy intentando hacer

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package kaprekar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Pillado
 */
public class Kaprekar {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int KAPREKAR = 6174;
        String nS;
        int casos, numAsc, numDes;
        int numero = 0;
        int cont = 0;
        int resta = 0;
        int contador = 0;

        System.out.println("Escribe el numero de casos");
        casos = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine();

        while(contador < casos){
            nS = entrada.nextLine();
            numero = ordDes(Integer.parseInt(cero(Integer.parseInt(nS))));

            if(nS.length() > 4){
            }else if(nS.equals(Integer.toString(KAPREKAR))){
                System.out.println("0");
            }else if(numDig(numero) == 1 || numero == 0){
                System.out.println("8");
            }else{
                numAsc = ordAsc(numero);
                numDes = Integer.parseInt(cero(ordDes(numero)));

                do{
                    if(numAsc > numDes){
                        resta = numAsc - numDes;
                        numAsc = ordAsc(resta);
                        numDes = Integer.parseInt(cero(ordDes(resta)));
                    }else if(numDes > numAsc){
                        resta = numDes - numAsc;
                        numAsc = ordAsc(resta);
                        numDes = Integer.parseInt(cero(ordDes(resta)));
                    }

                    cont++;

                    if(resta == KAPREKAR){
                        break;
                    }
                }while(true);

                System.out.println(cont);
                cont = 0;
                resta = 0;
            }
            contador++;
        }
    }
    /*
    Método contDig. Usado para contar el numero de dígitos que tiene el numero
    el numero lo convierto a string para luego recorrerlo con un bucle for y en 
    una variable contador almacenar i, cuando finalice el bucle el valor de i 
    corresponderá al numero de dígitos y este valor es asignado a contador
    */
    public static int contDig(int n){
        //Cuenta el numero de digitos de un numero
        int contador = 0;
        String nS = Integer.toString(n);

        for(int i = 0; i <= nS.length(); i++){
            contador = i;
        }

        return contador;
    }
    /*
    Método numDig. Este método lo uso para comprobar si hay algún dígito 
    distinto en el numero, debido a las consideraciones del problema que estoy 
    resolviendo aquí los números siempre tendrán 4 dígitos por lo tanto si hay 
    un numero con menos de 4 dígitos quiere decir que a la izquierda de este hay 
    ceros (Ejemplo: 0022) con lo cual si un numero viene con menos de 4 dígitos 
    entonces hay dos o mas dígitos distintos y esto lo controlo con el 
    if(nS.length() == 4). Si se cumple la condición del if, el numero lo 
    convierto a string para luego recorrerlo con un bucle for e ir añadiendo 
    cada dígito a una posición del array aN, en el array oc añado la primera 
    posición del array aN, con un bucle for recorro el array aN para en caso de 
    que en el array oc no aya ningún elemento del array aN añadirlo a oc. Si no 
    se cumple el if(nS.length() == 4) quiere decir que como minimo el numero 
    tiene dos dígitos distintos por lo tanto añado a oc dos números 
    cualesquiera, yo elegí el 4 pudiendo ser cualquiera ya que lo que me 
    interesa de este array es el tamaño que tendrá al final. El tamaño del array 
    oc es el que indica el numero de dígitos distintos que tiene el numero.
    */
    public static int numDig(int n){
        //Cuenta el numero de digitos distintos de un numero
        ArrayList<Integer> aN = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> oc= new ArrayList<>();

        String nS = Integer.toString(n);

        if(nS.length() == 4){

            for(int i = 0; i < nS.length(); i++){
                aN.add(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(nS.charAt(i))));
            }


            oc.add(aN.get(0));

            for (int i = 0; i < aN.size(); i++) {
                if(!oc.contains(aN.get(i))){
                    oc.add(aN.get(i));
                }
            }
        }else{
            oc.add(4);
            oc.add(4);
        }

        return oc.size();
    }
    /*
    Método ordAsc. Usado para ordenar un numero ascendente mente (Ejemplo: 
    1234). Convierto el numero en un string para recorrerlo con un bucle for e 
    ir añadiendo cada dígito a una posición de la lista, luego uso sort() para 
    ordenar la lista y como tengo que devolver un numero uso un bucle for para 
    recorrer la lista e ir añadiendo cada elemento de esta lista a un string. El 
    resultado es el numero ordenado.
    */
    public static int ordAsc(int n){
        int lisNum[] = new int [4];

        int numAsc;
        String nS = Integer.toString(n);
        String nA = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < nS.length(); i++){
            lisNum[i] = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(nS.charAt(i)));
        }

        Arrays.sort(lisNum);

        for(int i = 0; i < lisNum.length; i++){
            nA += Integer.toString(lisNum[i]);
        }

        numAsc = Integer.parseInt(nA);

        return numAsc;
    }
    /*
    Método ordDes. Usado para ordenar un numero descendente mente (Ejemplo: 
    4321). Aprovecho el método ordAsc para luego con un bucle for recorrer nA 
    desde el final hasta el principio para obtener el numero ordenado 
    descendiente mente.
    */
    public static int ordDes(int n){
        int numAsc = ordAsc(n);
        int numDes;

        String nA = Integer.toString(numAsc);
        String nD = "";

        for(int i = nA.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            nD += nA.charAt(i);
        }

        numDes = Integer.parseInt(nD);

        return numDes;
    }
    /*
    Método cero. Lo uso para añadir ceros a la derecha y así poder hacer las 
    correspondientes restas. Ejemplo: tenemos el numero 9909 que ordenado 
    ascendente mente seria 0999 y a su vez descendente mente seria 9990, con el 
    código que tengo tiene problemas con los ceros a la derecha ya que no los 
    incluía en el numero y es por eso que uso este método para añadírselos.
    */
    public static String cero(int n){
        String c = "";
        String nS = Integer.toString(n);


        switch (contDig(n)) {
            case 3:
                c = nS + "0";
                break;
            case 2:
                c = nS + "00";
                break;
            case 1:
                c = nS + "000";
                break;
            default:
                c = nS;
                break;
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación que nos ayude a comprender mejor tu solución, ya que responder solo con código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @Aprendiz, soy novato tanto programando como consultando en una comunidad y e pecado de pensar que entenderías el código así sin mas. Ya realice algunos cambios y espero que lo podáis entender mejor ahora

Comment: Quedó muy bien la edición con todos esos comentarios explicando el código +1